# Qt QListView - context menus?

Tags: qt, qlistview

I'm trying to add a context (right click) menu to a Qt QListView. I see in Qt 3.3 there is "contextMenuRequested" (which I could use) -  http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qlistview.html#contextMenuRequested. However, I can't see such a method in Qt4. Does anyone know how to add a context menu to a QListView?

Answer (score 20):

Depending on how you have set up the [ContextMenuPolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) in the `QWidget` you have a few options.

If you've set it to `Qt::DefaultContextMenu` then just override the `contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*)` protected function in `QWidget`. I believe that this is the default.

If you've set it to `Qt::ActionsContextMenu` then just add all your actions to your widget and let the Qt system handle showing the context menu.

Or if you've set it to `Qt::CustomContextMenu` you need to connect to the `customContextMenuRequested()` signal and implement your own context menu handler.

This is all documented in the [ContextMenuPolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) documentation available online.

Comment: Updated links to ContextMenuPolicy description:   
 [qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop)   and
 [qt4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but you can easily add a context menu to any widget by calling `QWidget::AddAction(QAction*)` with the actions that you want to add to your context menu and setting the context menu policy

```
widget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu);
```

the widget will prepare and show the context menu, all you need to do is hook up the actions `triggered()` signals to the appropriate handlers

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the signal has been removed but it's still a `QWidget` so you can always override

```
void QWidget::contextMenuEvent ( QContextMenuEvent* );
```

or

```
void QWidget::customContextMenuRequested( const QPoint& pos );
```

depending on your context menu policy setting for the widget.

Comment: customContextMenuRequested() is a signal, not an overridable function