# Popup windows menú in qt-creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a listview that shows the items in a folder and what I want is to open the Windows popupmenu when the right click is clicked.

Comment: Please, have a look into the doc. of [QListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistview-members.html) and search for "contextmenu".

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Qt QListView - context menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670690/7478597)